# Expected values regarding a hash table

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, probability

I'm working on a problem in my data structures textbook, and I'm getting stuck on it. I have a hash table of 16,000 slots. It's dealing with # of cities, and n = 15937 cities. I'm trying to figure out what the expected number of slots is that have exactly one city and then the same thing for two cities. I know how to find expected number of items per one slot and expected number of empty slots, but not sure if that's any use to me. Each slot has an equal chance of having an item inserted into it. Anyone have an idea of where I could start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

start with say 5 slots and 4 cities and then see if you extrapolate the relationship to 16,000

the first city can be assumed to be in the first slot

the second city has X% to be in the first slot and X% in the second ....

EDIT - another way to look at that is what are ALL the possible arrangements, and what percentages do you see

```
A1B1C1D1 is all for cities (A,B,C,D) are in bucket 1
A1B1C1D2 is ABC in bucket 1 and D is in bucket 2
A1B1C1D3 is ABC in bucket 1 and D is in bucket 3
A1B1C1D4 is ABC in bucket 1 and D is in bucket 4
A1B1C1D5 is ABC in bucket 1 and D is in bucket 5
A1B1C2D1 is ABD in bucket 1 C in bucket 2
.....
```

hope that helps

Comment: Well each city has a 20% chance to be in each slot right? First city goes to first slot. 2nd city has 1/5 chance to go in each slot?

Comment: Wait, would the expected number of slots to only have one city be (1/16000) * 15937?

Comment: @pfinferno - the idea is to blow out the whole tree - you may be able to deduce the formula for chance of all 4 cities in one bucket, the formula for number of buckets with 3 cities, with 2 cities, etc., the idea is to manually work it out with a small data set and then work up

Comment: Sorry, I was never good at statistics. Would it be something to do with combinations? Like, 5 choose 1 multiplied by 4 choose 1?

Comment: @pfinferno last hint - statistics is for people who can't do brute force coding to check every possibility

Comment: I appreciate your help man. I'm just still stuck. Is there another direction I could take to go about this? If item goes in slot 1, then there's an 80% chance it only has that item at the end (because it's a 20% chance the next items go into it vs. the other slots). Is that the right track?

Comment: @pfinferno - write some code to plot distribution of all possible places 4 cities could be in 5 buckets

Comment: Like this?
'
int main() 
{ 
int a,b,c,d; 
printf(" The permutations of a 4 digit number 1234 \n"); 
printf("________________________________... 
for(a=1; a<5; a++) 
{ 
for(b=1; b<5; b++) 
{ 
for(c=1; c<5; c++) 
{ 
for(d=1; d<5; d++) 
{ 
if(!(a==b || a==c || a==d || b==c || b==d || c==d)) 
printf("%d%d%d%d\n",a,b,c,d); 
} 
} 
} 
} 
system("pause"); 
return 0; 
}
'

Comment: @pfinferno - absolute last hint - collect the data, not just print it and then print out analysis - XXX/YYYY = Z% buckets have one city, the same for two, three, etc

Comment: Okay I'm trying something else. If I find the expected number of collisions in the hash table, then I subtract that along with the expected number of empty slots from the total, it should give me the slots with just 1?

Comment: @pfinferno: You said, "Sorry, I was never good at statistics". If you're going to be working with hash tables, it's a good idea to understand the basics of probability.